# Acessing the elements of a 1D array and 2D array in C using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to learn C,but I got stuck over the following piece of codes. What I understood from my basic knowledge about C is that the array name itself is a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. And elements in a 2D array is stored one row after the other.So I am trying print the values of elements in a 1D array and 2D array using array name as a pointer. But for the `Code 1` it is working as I expected. But `Code 2` is giving unexpected result *(It is giving the starting addresses of each row)*. What is the reason for this to happen? I think something is wrong with my understanding. Can anybody clarify the mistake.

```
// Code 1
//-------
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int array[2][3] = {{5, 7, 9}, {2, 5, 77}};
    int j;
    for (j=0; j < 6; j++)
        printf("%d\t", *(array+j));
    return 0;
}

//Code 2
//------
// #include <stdio.h>
// int main () {
//  int array[6] = {5, 7, 9, 2, 5, 77};
//  int j;
//  for (j=0; j < 6; j++)
//      printf("%d\t", *(array+j));
//  return 0;
// }
```

Comment: Define unexpected results

Comment: Has been asked thousands of times. Firstly: array is not a pointer. Secondly: read the FAQ http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html. Do a search on arrays and pointers here on SO.

Comment: you need simple pointer :( ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since multidimensional arrays are contiguous in memory, you can just grab a pointer to the first element of the array and use it as if it pointed to the first element of a one-dimensional array:

```
int array[2][3] = { { 5, 7, 9 }, { 2, 5, 77 } };
int *p = &array[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
```

Your original attempt, `*(array+j)` was wrong because it's equivalent to `array[j]`, which is an array itself, so you were trying to:

1. print a pointer (`array[j]`, being an array, decays into a pointer when passed to a function) as if it was an integer, using the `%d` format specifier - that invokes undefined behavior **and** at the same time it's not printing what you really wanted it to print;
2. access the array out of bounds (`array` has only two elements, both are of type `int [3]`, so you quickly run into undefined behavior when you access the 2nd, 3rd, ..., 5th element).

Answer (score 0):

You should code

```
 for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        printf("%d\t", t[i][j]);
 putc('\n');
```

Comment: I need to do it using pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For the two dimensional array, your code is not working. change

```
int j;
for (j=0; j < 6; j++)
    printf("%d\t", *(array+j));
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        printf("%d\t", *(*(array+i)+j));
```

For the pointer version, see @H2CO3's answer.

Comment: [This is not what OP is looking for.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905755/acessing-the-elements-of-a-1d-array-and-2d-array-in-c-using-pointer/17905774#17905774)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of code will work.

`sizeof(array) = 24` in both cases. Lets assume `array` starts at address `0x100` then `array+1` will give you `0x100 + 0x18 = 0x118` not `0x100 + 0x4 = 0x104` as you are expecting.

`0x18 = 24`.